# How to get private fields and call private methods in Advice wrapped method?

Tags: byte-buddy

Redefine method:

```
  private <T> void redefine(Class<T> type, UnaryOperator<DynamicType.Builder<T>> operation) {
    DynamicType.Builder<T> builder = new ByteBuddy().redefine(type);
    ClassLoader systemClassLoader = Entity.class.getClassLoader();

    operation
            .apply(builder)
            .make()
            .load(systemClassLoader, ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());
}
```

Use of Advice:

```
        redefine(ChunkGeneratorAbstract.class, builder -> builder
            .method(named("buildNoise")
                    .and(takesArguments(3)))
            .intercept(Advice.to(ChunkGeneratorAdvice.class).wrap(StubMethod.INSTANCE)));
```

ChunkGeneratorAdvice:

```
 @Advice.OnMethodExit
public static void buildNoise(GeneratorAccess generatoraccess, StructureManager structuremanager, IChunkAccess ichunkaccess,
                              @Advice.This ChunkGeneratorAbstract chunkGenerator) {

    int val = chunkGenerator.n;
    Object someVal = chunkGenerator.privateMethod();
}
```

**chunkGenerator.n** is a private field. How to get its value?

Also, how i can call private methods like **chunkGenerator.privateMethod()**?

Answer (score 1):

For a private field, you can use `Advice.FieldValue` as an annotation on a parameter to read and write from it. For a method call, you would need to use a `MemberSubstitution`. You would then declare an empty method in the advice class that has the same signature and call this method from your advice code. Later, you would use `MemberSubstitution` to switch the method calls.

Comment: Can you show an example on how to use `MemberSubstitution` to transform a private method of a class?

Comment: Check out BBs unit tests on MemberSubstitution. They document this quite extensively.